# If I wrap a react components in one big react component will they share props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to share props between all components but with a wrapper component
For example:

```js
const name = "Test"
return (
    <Wrapper myprops={name}>
      <Image/>
      <House/>
    </Wrapper>
)
```

So can I get the `myprops` from Image and House?

Comment: There's a concept in react called "context" that does that

Comment: @Federkun React.createContent? You talking this one?

Comment: yeah, https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Does the redux Provider work that way @Federkun, I'm making something like that

Comment: internally, redux use the context api.

Comment: Oh alright thanks for the help @Federkun

Comment: Props are ***not*** shared between components. You can provide props to children explicitly by passing them down as props to children or use the React context API to provide/consume them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context API is used to share data between components in different nesting levels, you can read this from [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

> Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by
> many components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly
> because it makes component reuse more difficult.

For your case, your components `Image` and `House` are at the same level. Instead, you can use the composition and pass the props to your inner children like this:

```
import React, { cloneElement } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const name = 'Test';

  return (
    <Parent>
      <Wrapper myprops={name}>
        <Image />
        <House />
      </Wrapper>
    </Parent>
  );
}

function Parent({ children }) {
  return children;
}

function Wrapper({ children, ...props }) {
  return <>{children.map((child) => cloneElement(child, { ...props }))}</>;
}

function Image(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>Image</div>;
}

function House(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>House</div>;
}
```

This is a simple demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szxqwg

Answer (score 0):

*The answer of **@Soufiane Boutahlil** is legit, But you are missing a **key** prop. Otherwise, React will go mad at you.*

```
function Wrapper({ children, ...props }) {
  return <>{children.map((child, i) => 
           <React.Fragment key={i}>
             cloneElement(child, { ...props }))
           </React.Fragment>}
         </>;
}
```